# Centering only certain equations in rmarkdown using Latex

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I am working in rmarkdown knitting to pdf. I have set equations (and everything else?) to default to left alignment using

```
classoption: fleqn
```

in the YAML metadata at the top of my rmarkdown file.

I was wondering how to specify certain equations to align in the center while still keeping the default alignment of text and equations to left. I have searched this forum and run many examples but the code never seems to work in rmarkdown.

Here is an example rmarkdown document.

```
---
title: "centering equations"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: null
  word_document: null
toc: yes
linestretch: 1.3
classoption: fleqn
header-includes: 
 - \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
 - \setlength\parindent{0pt}
---

This is some text

This is the equation I would have centered.

\begingroup\large
\begin{align*}
h(t_{ij}) = Pr[T_{i}=j|T_{i}\geq j].
\end{align*}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Seems to be a pure rmarkdown question and is therefore off toic here, sorry ...

Comment: Can you provide an example R Markdown document?

Comment: @Werner I should have supplied that. Have added an example document.

Comment: use `$$  eqn=stuff $$` for your centred equation?

Comment: Thans @David Carlisle. Unfortunately that still came out left-aligned

Comment: That's strange `fleqn` option has no affect on `$$` in latex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the equation inside a box that spans the entire `\linewidth`:

[image]

```
---
title: "centering equations"
output:
  pdf_document: default
classoption: fleqn
header-includes: 
 - \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
 - \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
---

This is some text

This is the equation I would like left aligned:
\[
  h(t_{ij}) = Pr[ T_i = j| T_i \geq j |
\]

This is the equation I would like centred:
\[
  \makebox[\linewidth]{$h(t_{ij}) = Pr[ T_i = j| T_i \geq j |$}
\]

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{centered text}

This is a set of equations to align centred:
\[
  \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
    \begin{aligned}
               f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
      ax^2 + bx + c &= g(x)
    \end{aligned}
  $}
\]
```